# Insert data into MySQL from Excel via Eclipse using Selenium and Testng

Tags: mysql, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I got struck while trying to do the coding part. Following is the part which i tried. I'm in need to know the @Test portion. I don't know to write the Selenium code to part to fetch the data from excel and to insert the data in MySQL.

```
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestBase;
import java.io.File;
import java.sql.*;
import jxl.*;

public class testng extends SeleneseTestBase{

@BeforeTest
public static void connection()
{

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
}
@BeforeTest     
public static void MysqlConnection()  //we need to add the Dataprovider name[name="DP"] to pass the data from excel sheet
{   
    try {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root", "admin");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("Testing Testfile1");
}

@DataProvider(name = "DP1")
public Object[][] createData1() throws Exception{
    Object[][] retObjArr=getTableArray("D:\\sakthi\\selenium\\data3.xls","DataPool", "mysqldata");
    return(retObjArr);
}

@Test (dataProvider = "DP1")
public void testDataProviderExample(int id, int plist_id, String email) throws Exception {    


  //This is the part where i'm in need of help


}

public String[][] getTableArray(String xlFilePath, String sheetName, String tableName) throws Exception{
    String[][] tabArray=null;

        Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(xlFilePath));
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName); 
        int startRow,startCol, endRow, endCol,ci,cj;
        Cell tableStart=sheet.findCell(tableName);
        startRow=tableStart.getRow();
        startCol=tableStart.getColumn();

        Cell tableEnd= sheet.findCell(tableName, startCol+1,startRow+1, 100, 64000,  false);                

        endRow=tableEnd.getRow();
        endCol=tableEnd.getColumn();
        System.out.println("startRow="+startRow+", endRow="+endRow+", " +"startCol="+startCol+", endCol="+endCol);
        tabArray=new String[endRow-startRow-1][endCol-startCol-1];
        ci=0;

        for (int i=startRow+1;i<endRow;i++,ci++){
            cj=0;
            for (int j=startCol+1;j<endCol;j++,cj++){
                tabArray[ci][cj]=sheet.getCell(j,i).getContents();
            }
        }    

    return(tabArray);
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Selenium is used to control a web browser, you don't need it open an excel file and write to a DB.

Comment: can you tell the java code what i need to put inside that @Test part?

Comment: i need to insert the excel data which i'm trying to import from csv file to the mysql database(test), table name(imported_tbl)